# Should I limit product quantities if it's ridiculously high?

Tags: mysql

Recently in my eCommerce store someone placed a fake order. This person ordered a couple of products 2.147.483.648 times. This caused my database to slow down (integer overflow I think?).The order was deleted and the user blocked.

It did get me wondering; should I add a "maximum order quantity"? It is not uncommon for people to order a 500 quantaties of a product but much more is rare.

I store `quantity` as `int(11)` in a MySQL `order_details` table.

How should I handle this? How do other websites do this? If someone orders a ridiculous high amount I should just lower it?

```
if ($quantity >= 1000000) {
    $quantity = 99999;
}
```

Comment: You probably validate the input data at some point. In the validation step, you include the check about the quantity if you need it. In case of a too large number, report an error to the user - otherwise continue. If I ordered 10 000 items of something but you charged and delivered 9999 of them because of "magic", I would be pretty pissed with you.

Comment: Yes. You need to validate user input. What if my cat accidentally sits on the 'add to basket' button. Will I get blocked for that? Not fair.